# No mapped ORM entities, Using doctrine 2 and Zend Framework 2

Tags: php, zend-framework, doctrine-orm

It might be something in my configuration file, because it's not showing the mappings anywhere, but I have checked and it seems to be correct according to all sources.

I've tried several ways to try to fix this but no matter what, once I run

```
$ vendor/bin/doctrine-module orm:generate:entities -v module/Users/src/Users/Entity/
```

I get

```
No Metadata Classes to process.
```

And if I run

```
$ vendor/bin/doctrine-module orm:info
```

I get

[Exception] You do not have any mapped Doctrine ORM entities according to the current  configuration. If you have entities or mapping files you should check your mapping configuration for errors.

Here's the contents of the  module.config.php, the module is named 'Users'.

```
<?php
namespace Users;

return array(
  // ...
  // Doctrine config
  'doctrine' => array(
    'driver' => array(
      __NAMESPACE__ . '_driver' => array(
        'class' => 'Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\Driver\AnnotationDriver',
          'cache' => 'array',
          'paths' => array(__DIR__ . '/../src/' . __NAMESPACE__ . '/Entity')
      ),
        'orm_default' => array(
          'drivers' => array(
            __NAMESPACE__ . '\Entity' => __NAMESPACE__ . '_driver'
          )
        )
    )
  )
);
```

Here's my entity, just in case.

```
<?php 

namespace Users\Entity;

  //Imports from mapping classes
  use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\Entity;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\Table;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\Index;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\Id;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\GeneratedValue;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\Column;

// Entity and index creation
/**
 *User Entity
 *
 *@Entity
 *@Table(indexes={
 *    @Index(name="idx_username", columns="username"),
 *    @Index(name="idx_email", columns="email")
 *})
 */
class User
{
  /**  
   *@var int
   *
   *@Id
   *@generatedValue
   *
   *@Column(type="integer")
   */
  protected $id=NULL;
  /**  
   *@var string
   *
   *@Column(type="string",length=50,nullable=true)
   */
  protected $username=NULL;
  /**
   *@var string
   *
   *@Column(type="string",length=254,nullable=true)
   */
  protected $email=NULL;
  /**
   *@ORM\Column(type="binary",length=60,nullable=true)
   */
  protected $password=NULL;
  /**
   *@var int
   *
   *@Column(type="integer"nullable=true)
   */
  protected $avatar_id=NULL;
  /**
   *@var string
   *
   *@Column(type="string",length=25,nullable=true)
   */  
  protected $name=NULL;
  /**
   *@var string
   *
   *@Column(type="string",length=50,nullable=true)
   */
  protected $surname=NULL;
  /**
   *@var string
   *
   *@Column(type="string",length=255)
   */
  protected $bio='';
  /**
   *@var string
   *
   *@Column(type="string",length=255)
   */  
  protected $location='';
  /**
   *@var int
   *
   *@Column(type="smallint",nullable=true)
   */
  protected $gender=NULL;
}
```

And finally here's my module.php

```
<?php

namespace Users;

use Zend\Mvc\ModuleRouteListener;
use Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent;

class Module
{

  public function onBootstrap(MvcEvent $e)
  {
    $eventManager        = $e->getApplication()->getEventManager();
    $moduleRouteListener = new ModuleRouteListener();
    $moduleRouteListener->attach($eventManager);
  }
  public function getConfig()
  {
    return include __DIR__ . '/config/module.config.php';
  }

  public function getAutoloaderConfig()
  {
    return array(
      'Zend\Loader\StandardAutoloader' => array(
        'namespaces' => array(
          __NAMESPACE__ => __DIR__ . '/src/' . __NAMESPACE__,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

And the tree for my module

```
Users
    ├── config
    │   └── module.config.php
    ├── #Module.php#
    ├── Module.php
    └── src
        └── Users
            └── Entity
                ├── User.php
                └── User.php~
```

Any and all help is much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: That's a lot of code but it would be helpful if you could take a little more to explain what your actual problems.

Comment: The question has been edited for clarity

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the answer, the problem was I was using the **NAMESPACE** property and my entity didn't have the same name as the namespace on the module.config.php I solved it by changing all the namespaces from 'Users' to User and changing all file module names.

for example, the original namespace on module.config.php was 'Users', I changed that to 'User'. worked  like a charm.

Here's the corrected tree of files I got in the end.

```
User
├── config
│   ├── module.config.php
│   └── module.config.php~
├── Module.php
├── Module.php~
└── src
    └── User
        └── Entity
            ├── User.php
            └── User.php~
```

Be careful about consistency peeps :)